# Zod refine arguments provide the unvalidated raw data

Tags: zod

```
const dateValidator = z
  .string({ required_error: 'expected YYYY-MM-DD', invalid_type_error: 'expected YYYY-MM-DD' })
  .regex(/^\d{4}\-(0[1-9]|1[012])\-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$/, { message: 'must be in YYYY-MM-DD format' })
  .transform((v) => new Date(v + 'T00:00:00.000Z'))

const validateStartEndDates = (searchParams: URLSearchParams) =>
  z
    .object({ start: dateValidator, end: dateValidator })
    .refine(({ start, end }) => { // start, end return raw string
      return end.getTime() >= start.getTime()
    }, 'end date must be larger or equal to start date')
    .parse({ start: searchParams.get('start'), end: searchParams.get('end') })
```

If I hover my mouse on `start`, `end` on `refine` args, they show up as the transformed Date type correctly, but if I `console.log` out those values from refine args, they are raw string format, this ends up `end.getTime()` throwing an error.

Comment: What is the error you're seeing? If you `console.log` a regular `Date`, I suspect it is converted to a string for logging which might be why you're seeing a string.

Comment: it says `getTime` is not defined, which makes sense cuz the start and end are not the transformed Date types. It will simply give me the raw string input(ex. "2022-01-01")

Comment: from what I understand the arguments of refine function should be the validated, transformed data, not the raw data. If its not a date type, it should fail in the previous validations and not even go to the `refine` stage

Comment: The reason I ask is because if I dump you code completely unchanged into a codesandbox and log `console.log(validateStartEndDates(new URLSearchParams("start=1994-10-02&end=1995-10-02")));` I see a correctly parsed output. So the bug seems to be something else. I was hoping to help you track it down. https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-keldysh-ok8okp

Comment: Yea for the valid inputs int works, but if u put wrong values like start=123123, refine will fail. It should not even go to refine stage cuz it should fail the regex test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was able to reproduce this bug using zod version 3.20.6 (among other related issues).  I created an issue for this on github.

https://github.com/colinhacks/zod/issues/2113

In your case, it's the `.regex()` that I think is causing the problem.  As a work-around until they fix it, you can use `transform` to do your validation as described in their docs.

There are other scenarios that can also cause refines to be invoked on already-invalidated inputs.